# PayPal Direct Payments

Tags: paypal, payment

I am developing an e-commerce site in ASP .Net 4.0 C#. I want to use PayPal for receiving payments but through credit/debit cards so that customer never leaves my site. Please provide some sample code/links for this.

Note: I don't want to use HTML form tag for submitting my requests but wana make use of the API/ Web request.

Many many thanks for the help

Regards
Vivek

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for PayPal's .NET NVP SDK:
https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_AspNet_NVP_SDK.zip

You'll need to generate API credentials, here's a tutorial:
https://ppmts.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/ppdts.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=737

You can find other PayPal SDKs at www.paypal.com/sdk

I hope this helps.
Lorefold

Comment: the API reference for DirectPayment will come in handy too: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoDirectPayment

Answer (score 1):

Exactly; as mentioned previously, you'll want to use PayPal Website Payments Pro and/or PayPal Payflow Pro in that case. Website Payments Pro is only available in the US/CA and UK, whereas Payflow Pro is available in AU/NZ and US.
Either of these two products will allow you to process cards on your site.

Keep in mind though, that processing cards on your own site will mean you'll need to adhere to PCI DSS and be compliant these regulations. By redirecting buyers to PayPal to enter their card details / financial data, you can shift that liability to PayPal.

Comment: Yeah, it involves a $25-30 per month fee, but can work quite nicely.  And yes, just make sure you take the necessary security precautions.